# Bold page number in list of figures and list of tables

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, bold

I want to write page numbers with bold face in lot and lof. I am writing a PhD thesis and there is a thesis template. Relevant part of lof is as follows:

```
\renewcommand\listoffigures{
    \vspace*{\ChapterMargin}
    {\chapter*{\listfigurename}
    \vspace*{-20pt}
    \hfill\vspace*{0.5truecm}{\bf\underline{Page}

    \let\orig@numberline\numberline
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}
    \renewcommand*{\numberline}[1]{%
    \orig@numberline{\bf\figurename\ ##1}\hspace{-7pt}{\bf:}\hspace{7pt}}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\bf{\protect\listfigurenameToC}}
    \setlength{\th@oldparskip}{\parskip}
    \setlength{\parskip}{\LoFparskip}
    \@starttoc{lof}
    \setlength{\parskip}{\th@oldparskip}
    \let\numberline\orig@numberline
    }
```

Sample view:
**Figure 2.1:** Figure caption............................................. **5**

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but

I don't like the portion of the class/package (not template) code you have shown. the macro `\bf` is long out of date, use `\textbf{this will be bold}`. I can't run the code as there are bits of it (e.g., `\LoFparskip`) that are not defined.

I'm not going to try and replicate the results of your code but you may well be better off using the facilities of the `tocloft` package (`> texdoc tocloft`) where to set the pagenumbers bold use

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\bfseries} % bold page number for chapters
\renewcommand{\cftsectionpagefont}{\bfseries} % bold section page numbers
% etc
```

Good luck.l

Comment: Hi Peter, macro `\bf` might be old but still works. Sorry for `\LoFparskip`. Related part for `\LoFparskip` is as follows: `\newlength{\LoFparskip}   
\setlength{\LoFparskip}{0em}`. tocloft corrupts thesis template so bad.

Comment: I couldn't figure out which of these codes is the page number. Do you have an idea?

Comment: `\bf` has been deprecated since at least 1994.  Any code that uses it, like your snippet,  is not exactly up to date. You have not said what class you are using so I have no idea why `tocloft` doesn't work with it, and am not interested in finding out. GOM